# How to parse json using sapui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

I am currently parsing json and displaying the data  in a table control using sapui5,but i am unable to parse inner objects values

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
    <title>Table example</title>

    <!-- Load UI5, select gold reflection theme and the "commons" and "table" control libraries -->
    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
       src='resources/sap-ui-core.js'
       data-sap-ui-theme='sap_goldreflection'
       data-sap-ui-libs='sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table'></script>

    <script>

        // create the DataTable control
        var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({editable:true});

        // define the Table columns
        var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"{comments/data/from/username}"});     // short binding notation
        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Group"}), template: oControl }));

        var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"{comments/data/from/id}"}); // short binding notation
        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Group Text"}), template: oControl }));

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        var aData = 
       jQuery.ajax({

                url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=d6ff37e000de4fc7882e4e5fccfff236",  // for different servers cross-domain restrictions need to be handled

                dataType: "json",

                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // callback called when data is received
                    var JsonData = data;
                   oModel.setData(JsonData);  // fill the received data into the JSONModel
                    alert("sparta");

                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert("error");
                }

            });
        // create a JSONModel, fill in the data and bind the Table to this model


      // oModel.setData(aData);
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindRows("/data");

        // finally place the Table into the UI
        oTable.placeAt("content");

    </script>

    </head>
    <body class='sapUiBody'>
        <div id='content'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do i fetch the inner element values such as username and id etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "user/usernme");
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "User Name"}), template: oControl}));

var oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "user/id");
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "UserID"}), template: oControl}));
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/JSONModel.html

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = oModel.getData();
```

Using this you get the data for that model, then you can loop through the data or parse it.

Comment: Could you also tell me how can we apply filters to a JSon model. Any idea?

Comment: You can go through this docment that give brief . JSONModel is a collection of your data, You can filter it or you can set filters  when you do data binding  it's totally on the requirements.https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html